# Parallel sort using web workers is slower than serial sort (merge sort)

Tags: javascript, mergesort, web-worker

I am trying to make parallel version of merge sort algorithm using web-workers.

Parallel version is very slow on small arrays (due to overhead of promises and web-workers i think) but surprisingly it is also slower than serial sort on big arrays

Parallel version

```
console.log(navigator.hardwareConcurrency + " threads")
var blob = new Blob([
    `onmessage = function(e) { 

function merge_sort(arr) {
  let length = arr.length;        
  if (length < 2) {
    return arr
  }
 let middle = Math.floor(length/2)
 let left = arr.slice(0, middle)     
 let right = arr.slice(middle)     
 return merge(merge_sort(left), merge_sort(right))
}

function merge(left, right) {
  let result = [];
  let i=0;
  let j=0;
  while(i < left.length && j < right.length) {
    if(left[i] < right[j]) {
      result.push(left[i]) ;
      i++;       
    } else {                       
      result.push(right[j]);
      j++;
    }
  }
  return result.concat(left.slice(i)).concat(right.slice(j))
} 
   if(e.data.job==='sort'){
    postMessage(merge_sort(e.data.arr));
}else{
     postMessage(merge(e.data.arr[0],e.data.arr[1]))
}
         }`
]);  
var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var v1 = new Worker(blobURL);
var v2 = new Worker(blobURL);
var v3 = new Worker(blobURL);
var v4 = new Worker(blobURL);

function merge(left, right) {
    let result = [];
    let i = 0;
    let j = 0;
    while (i < left.length && j < right.length) {
        if (left[i] < right[j]) {
            result.push(left[i]);
            i++;
        } else {
            result.push(right[j]);
            j++;
        }
    }
    return result.concat(left.slice(i)).concat(right.slice(j))
}

var arr = Array.from({
    length: 20000000
}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 50000000));

var half1 = []
var half2 = []
var half_1 = []
var half_2 = []
var half_3 = []
var half_4 = []
let middle = Math.floor(arr.length / 2)
half1 = arr.slice(0, middle)
half2 = arr.slice(middle)

let middlehalf1 = Math.floor(half1.length / 2)
half_1 = half1.slice(0, middlehalf1)
half_2 = half1.slice(middlehalf1)

let middlehalf2 = Math.floor(half2.length / 2)
half_3 = half2.slice(0, middlehalf2)
half_4 = half2.slice(middlehalf2)
var t0 = performance.now();

var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    v1.postMessage({
        job: 'sort',
        arr: half_1
    });
    v1.addEventListener('message', event => resolve(event.data));
    v1.addEventListener('error', reject);
})
var p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    v2.postMessage({
        job: 'sort',
        arr: half_2
    });
    v2.addEventListener('message', event => resolve(event.data));
    v2.addEventListener('error', reject);
})
var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    v3.postMessage({
        job: 'sort',
        arr: half_3
    });
    v3.addEventListener('message', event => resolve(event.data));
    v3.addEventListener('error', reject);
})
var p4 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    v4.postMessage({
        job: 'sort',
        arr: half_4
    });
    v4.addEventListener('message', event => resolve(event.data));
    v4.addEventListener('error', reject);
})

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, p4]).then(function(results) {
    //console.log( )
    var p5 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        v1.addEventListener('message', event => resolve(event.data));
        v1.addEventListener('error', reject);
    })
    var p6 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        v2.addEventListener('message', event => resolve(event.data));
        v2.addEventListener('error', reject);
    })
    v1.postMessage({
        job: 'merge',
        arr: [results[0], results[1]]
    });
    v2.postMessage({
        job: 'merge',
        arr: [results[2], results[3]]
    });

    Promise.all([p5, p6]).then(function(arrays) {
        merge(arrays[0], arrays[1])
        var t1 = performance.now();
        console.log(`merge_sort took ${(t1 - t0) / 1000} seconds`)
    })

});
```

Serial version

```
function merge_sort(arr) {
  let length = arr.length;        
  if (length < 2) {
    return arr
  }
 let middle = Math.floor(length/2)
 let left = arr.slice(0, middle)     
 let right = arr.slice(middle)     
 return merge(merge_sort(left), merge_sort(right))
}

function merge(left, right) {
  let result = [];
  let i=0;
  let j=0;
  while(i < left.length && j < right.length) {
    if(left[i] < right[j]) {
      result.push(left[i]) ;
      i++;       
    } else {                       
      result.push(right[j]);
      j++;
    }
  }
  return result.concat(left.slice(i)).concat(right.slice(j))
}
var BigArray =Array.from({ length: 20000000 }, ()=>Math.floor(Math.random() * 50000000)); 
var t0 = performance.now();
merge_sort(BigArray)
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log(`merge_sort took ${(t1 - t0) / 1000} seconds`)
```

Also i am looking for a better solution with parallel sort (my use of promises looks awful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too surprised it's slower on large arrays, given that you're **copying** the data between threads, and copying it at least once unnecessarily (by using `concat`).

If you're really sorting *numbers*, you can use one of the [type array types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) and *transfer* ownership of the arrays back and forth rather than copying their contents. That would let you reduce the amount of copying. If your starting point is a single array, the only copying would be to the individual typed arrays for the individual workers and then copying from those individual arrays back to the main one.

You can even go a step further depending on what platforms you need to support by using [shared memory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer) so that there's only one copy of the array, and each worker is just working (initially) on its own part of it. Shared memory is enabled on Chrome on platforms where its site-isolation feature can protect against Spectre-style vulnerabilities. The last I checked it was disabled in Firefox and either disabled or not implemented in other browsers.

But if it's not really numbers you're sorting, neither of those will work as they're tied to typed arrays.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasn't able to use typed arrays and array buffers in merge sort, but i used it in quick sort and got very good performance grow on big arrays